# Php file executes 2 times with htaccess redirect

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have htaccess file which contain:

```
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

index.php:

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE SteamID = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($steamid) . "'", $db);
```

When I opening index.php, mysql_query executes 2 times, and column Views every time increases in 2.
Why?

### added:

I made test.php with content:

```
<?
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', '****', '******');
mysql_select_db("*****", $db);
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET Views = Views + 1 WHERE SteamID = '76561198037192367'", $db);
?>
loaded
```

this code is executing 3 times!!
when I delete .htaccess everything is working properly. It's really strange...

Comment: silly question, but is the $steamid actually listed in the table twice?  can you show more of the index.php code?  how do you know it is executing twice, or are you just seeing the double increment?

Answer (score 2):

You're rewriting . which will match everything; static files like CSS and JS, and typical browser requests like /favicon.ico.

Try adding a RewriteCond to prevent the rule from matching existing files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Untested!

You could check whether or not this is the issue without being able to see access logs by having the rule respond to a test URL:

```
RewriteRule /test/ test.php [L]
```

Still untested!

An alternative to log files could be dev tools like Firebug which would allow you to see all requests made by a browser.

Comment: Have a look at RewriteCond (http://httpdpache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond). It will let you filter the rule to not respond to files.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example

Comment: Yes, but often browsers will make extra requests for things like /favicon.ico without instruction. Can you see your server access logs to see what actually happens when you run the script?

Comment: I'm sorry, I have the same htaccess file as you posted above, I just didn't post entire htaccess file. Unfortunately I have not access to log file

Comment: Thank-you, I forgot about this, I'll try it in 10 hours later.

Comment: I've edited htaccess file redirect to test.php as you said, now it is increasing in 2. I thing it's apache bug, and file loads 2 times, when someone open file, and after redirect

Answer (score 0):

The rules aren't directly causing the `index.php` file to get loaded twice. There's probably something in index.php, or the HTML content that is returned, that makes the browser load something (like an image, script, style, etc?) that the rule is catching and rewriting back to `index.php`. This makes it so when you load a page in a browser that gets routed to `index.php`, `index.php` actually gets ran twice.

You're either going to have to modify the HTML content that `index.php` outputs, modify the `index.php` script so that the query only gets executed when specific `_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`'s are requested, or add restriction conditions to the `RewriteRule . index.php [L]` rule so that it only loads once.